# Loop the button selection

Tags: python, loops, selenium, button, getelementbyid

I am trying to automate the selection process. In the sample below, I am trying to select the buttons by ID. Instead of writing multiple lines of code, I want to loop through the selection.

My script is :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoAlertPresentException
import unittest, time, re

class NewTest(unittest.TestCase):
def setUp(self):
    self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
    self.base_url = "https://developer.mozilla.org/"
    self.verificationErrors = []
    self.accept_next_alert = True

def test_new(self):
    driver = self.driver
    driver.get(self.base_url + "/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio")
    driver.find_element_by_id("contactChoice1").click()
    driver.find_element_by_id("contactChoice2").click()
    driver.find_element_by_id("contactChoice3").click()

def is_element_present(self, how, what):
    try: self.driver.find_element(by=how, value=what)
    except NoSuchElementException as e: return False
    return True

def is_alert_present(self):
    try: self.driver.switch_to_alert()
    except NoAlertPresentException as e: return False
    return True

def close_alert_and_get_its_text(self):
    try:
        alert = self.driver.switch_to_alert()
        alert_text = alert.text
        if self.accept_next_alert:
            alert.accept()
        else:
            alert.dismiss()
        return alert_text
    finally: self.accept_next_alert = True
```

---

HTML is:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio

can any one help me to do this

Thanks

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE), and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) This will help you debug your own programs and solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and the execution result including any error messages so we can better help you. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a list of all elements with type="radio" with:

```
find_elements_by_xpath
```

Then for each webelement in the list, you can do an

```
element.click();
```

Something like:

```
ids = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//input[@type="radio"]')
for ii in ids:
ii.click();
```

Comment: what i shared HTML was sample. i have similar but buttons. is is possible by ID

Comment: Yes, you can use (in this example): //*[contains(@id, 'contactChoice')]

Comment: ids = driver.find_elements_by_id('//input[@type="radio"]')
for ii in ids
ii.click();
like this?

Comment: No, problem with that is, id looks for absolute id. So unless all elements have same id, its going to be either xpath or css selector.

Comment: to be exact i have like this

driver.find_element_by_id("Product").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("id1").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("id1").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("id2").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("id2").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("id3").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("id3").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("id4").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("id4").click()

Comment: i want to loop this

Comment: In that case, you need to do: driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(@id, 'id')]") - If they are all <button..., //button. If they are all <a..., //a. If they are all <input... use //input. With the xpath, its going to scan all elements on the webpage with an ID, where ID contains the text id. So it will take id1, id2, id3 etc.

Comment: they all are buttons for example
<input type="button" name="but1" class="button3" id="0" style="background: url(https://img.png); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: 140%; background-color: #FFE676; background-position: center; height:40px; width:5%;">

Comment: Ah, in that case you are going to need:  driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//input[contains(@class, 'button')]")

Comment: for ii in ids - invalid syntax here

Comment: may be missing semicolon at the end. it should be like for ii in ids:

Comment: its not selecting the buttons

Comment: try with the x-path "//input[@type='button' and starts-with('but') and @id]"

Comment: issue is button will be different for each like
apple 
orange
banana

Comment: As long as it has a common identifier (like classname containing the word button) the xpath expression should suffice.. What exception are you getting?

Comment: ids = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(x-path "//input[@type='button' and starts-with('col') and @id]")
        for ii in ids:
            ii.click();
-invalid syntax